# Javascript: Build data for sunburst chart

Tags: javascript

I want to build a sunburst chart using echarts and it's a children -> grandchildren...structure. I used https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=sunburst-simple as an example to copy from.
My data is flat when I got it from backend.

```
const data = [
  {
    region: 'EMEA',
    username: 'MG',
    priority: 'P3',
    application: 'G1',
    count: 1
  },
  {
    region: 'EMEA',
    username: 'NRO',
    priority: 'P3',
    application: 'G1',
    count: 10
  },
  {
    region: 'APAC',
    username: 'WY',
    priority: 'P2',
    application: 'E7',
    count: 1
  },
  {
    region: 'APAC',
    username: 'WY',
    priority: 'P3',
    application: 'M2',
    count: 8
  },
  {
    region: 'APAC',
    username: 'SZ',
    priority: 'P3',
    application: 'G1',
    count: 3
  },
  {
    region: 'APAC',
    username: 'LW',
    priority: 'P2',
    application: 'E7',
    count: 3
  },
  {
    region: 'APAC',
    username: 'LW',
    priority: 'P3',
    application: 'G1',
    count: 6
  },
  {
    region: 'APAC',
    username: 'FYQ',
    priority: 'P3',
    application: 'M2',
    count: 3
  },
  {
    region: 'APAC',
    username: 'SF',
    priority: 'P3',
    application: 'G1',
    count: 1
  },
  {
    region: 'APAC',
    username: 'SCH',
    priority: 'P3',
    application: 'M2',
    count: 1
  },
  {
    region: 'APAC',
    username: 'ZZ',
    priority: 'P3',
    application: 'E5',
    count: 4
  },
  {
    region: 'APAC',
    username: 'ZZ',
    priority: 'P3',
    application: 'M2',
    count: 2
  },
  {
    region: 'India',
    username: 'MPG',
    priority: 'P3',
    application: 'E5',
    count: 2
  },
  {
    region: 'India',
    username: 'MPG',
    priority: 'P3',
    application: 'N8',
    count: 2
  },
  {
    region: 'India',
    username: 'PPP',
    priority: 'P1',
    application: 'E5',
    count: 1
  },
  {
    region: 'India',
    username: 'PPP',
    priority: 'P2',
    application: 'M2',
    count: 1
  },
  {
    region: 'India',
    username: 'HKR',
    priority: 'P3',
    application: 'E7',
    count: 3
  },
  {
    region: 'India',
    username: 'HKR',
    priority: 'P2',
    application: 'R3',
    count: 1
  },
  {
    region: 'India',
    username: 'DSA',
    priority: 'P3',
    application: 'G4',
    count: 2
  },
  {
    region: 'India',
    username: 'ASA',
    priority: 'P2',
    application: 'E7',
    count: 3
  },
  {
    region: 'India',
    username: 'ASA',
    priority: 'P3',
    application: 'G1',
    count: 1
  },
  {
    region: 'NA',
    username: 'AAM',
    priority: 'P3',
    application: 'E7',
    count: 15
  },
  {
    region: 'NA',
    username: 'AAM',
    priority: 'P3',
    application: 'G1',
    count: 4
  }
]
```

I need to build the children list dynamically - the outmost to the inner most circles could be region-application-priority or region-username-application or region-priority-application-username

I have build a children list:   const children = ['region','application','priority'];

Can someone please advise how can I aggregate it to something like

```
const dataSet =[
name: 'India', //the first item in the children is region, so pull the first region = 'India'
value: 16, //sum of region === 'India'
children:[
  {name: 'E5',
  value: 3, //sum of region === 'India' && application === 'E5'
     children:[
         {name: p3, value: 1},
         {name: p2, value: 2}
     
    ]
   },

   {
      name: 'N8',
      value: 2,
      children:{p3: 2}
  },

 {
     name:...
 }

]
```

Appreciate if you can provide some comments.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one way(might not be a good way though...)

```
const children = ['region','application','priority'];
const dataArray = new Array();
data.forEach((d, idx)=>{
                        const count = d.count
                        
                        children.forEach((child,index)=>{
                            const name = d[child];
                            const item = {name: name, value: count}
                            if(index === 0){
                                let temp = dataArray.find((o)=>{return o.name === name})
                                if(temp){
                                    temp.value += count
                                }else{
                                    dataArray.push(item)                                
                                }
                            }else{
                            
                                const previousKeys = children.slice(0, index)
                                const firstKey = previousKeys.shift()
                                const firstValue = d[firstKey]
                                let temp = dataArray.find((o)=>{return o.name === firstValue})
                                previousKeys.forEach((key,i)=>{
                                    const v = d[key]
                                    
                                
                                     temp = temp.children.find((o)=>{return o.name ===v})
                                    
                                     
                                
                                     
                                
                                
                                });
                                
                                
                                if(!temp.children)
                                {
                                     temp.children = new Array()
                                 }
                                 
                                 let m = temp.children
                                 let n = m.find((o)=>{return o.name === item.name})
                                 if(n){
                                    n.value += item.value
                                 }else{
                                    m.push(item)
                                 }
                                
                            }
                        
                        });
                        
                        
                    });
```

The key point is: when you are building the next level, the previous level should have been built already. That's the part i used in the  previousKeys.forEach((key,i)=>{} iteration. It moved the temp to the "just one level up" of the "item", and then check the item name existence & decide to push a new item, or merge the item into the existing slot.

The children variable decides the sunburst chart's sequence and level(from inner most to outside)